# How do I sum up all the sizes of an array property and support a missing array in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to get a grand total of all tags.

```
    let topics = await ReadSchema.aggregate([{
      $group: {
          "_id": "$id",
          count: { $size: { "$ifNull": [ "$summary.topics", [] ] } }
      }
    }]);
```

I get the error: `server error MongoError: unknown group operator '$size'`

Bonus points if you can remove duplicate "topics" in the total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't allow `$size` as accumulator operator,

The `$group`'s field Computed using the accumulator operators. The  operator must be one of the following accumulator operators are: `$accumulator`, `$addToSet`, `$avg`, `$first`, `$last`, `$max`, `$mergeObjects`, `$min`, `$push`, `$stdDevPop`, `$stdDevSamp`, `$sum`, for more details [refer $group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#accumulator-operator),

- use `$sum` before `$size` operator,

```
let topics = await ReadSchema.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$id",
            count: { 
                $sum: {
                    $size: { 
                        "$ifNull": [ "$summary.topics", [] ] 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

---

**Remove duplicate `topics` in the total:**

- `$addToSet` to topics, make unique array of topics array
- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `topics` array and get union of all `topics` tags
  using `$setUnion` and, `$size` to get total count of unique topics

```
let topics = await ReadSchema.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      topics: {
        $addToSet: { $ifNull: [ "$summary.topics", [] ] }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id: 1,
      count: {
        $size: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$topics",
            initialValue: [],
            in: { $setUnion: ["$$this", "$$value"] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

---

**Suggestions:**

- match topics is array condition in first stage in your query, `$type: 4` indicates topics field has array data type or not, this will filter your documents before `$group` stage and you do not longer need to check `$ifNull` condition in `$group` stage, you can remove that condition.
- for query optimization you can put index on `summary.topics` field.

  - how index works refer [index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/index.html)
  - create index refer [db.collection.createIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/)

```
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        { "summary.topics": { $type: 4 } },
        { "summary.topics": { $ne: [] } }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: I found the reduce function is incredibly expensive and takes around 30 seconds. on a relatively small dataset. How would I add an index to `summary.topics`?

Comment: yes it could be expensive, there is a other option using `$unwind` check [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e9s3-uRO6us) query, it could be helpful to you, again $unwind is a expensive operation as well, so my suggestion is to do this kind of process in client side language after your group query.

Comment: i have updated the answer with reference link for create index at suggestion part. you can do like this `db.collection.createIndex({ "summary.topics": 1 })`, 1 indicates ascending order index, -1 indicates descending order index.

Comment: Can you check my answer. Its much faster and doesn't need an index: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65464209/33522

Answer (score 1):

I found a faster way to remove duplicates and count size of an embedded array document.

```
    let topics = await ReadSchema.aggregate([
      {
        $project: {
          _id: '0',
          topics: { $ifNull: ['$summary.topics', []] },
        },
      },
      { $unwind: '$topics' },
      { $group: { _id: '0', topics: { $addToSet: '$topics' } } },
      {
        $project: {
          count: { $size: '$topics' },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

First we create a projection with just the topics. It will be an array of objects which contain the topics array for each document, we use `$ifNull` which will default to an empty array for documents where the embedded `summary.topics` array is missing.

We then `$unwind` that array of arrays into one flat array. Then `$group` the array using `$addToSet` which will implicitly remove duplicates by its nature.

We then `$project` a new document with a `count` property that takes the `$size` of the new array (as duplicates are now removed).

Comment: this is good, you found faster approach,  i think you can do it without $ifNull, when you do $unwind it will remove null and empty result documents from. just reference see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d9hB7Byi2cY)

Comment: If I'm not mistake `$unwind` ignores missing data unless you use the flag `preserveMissingData` or something like that. I was looking for something like "$unwind summary.topics as topics"

Comment: yes that what i am talking about, when you just do `$unwind: "$tokens"` it will ignore missing fields, you don't need to format that to blank array $ifNull in $project stage,